# How to add certain number of rows based on values on the rows of another variable

Tags: r, rbind, newrow

```
date        time    td  number
20150102    80000   -1  0
20150102    80001   -1  2
20150102    80002   1   0
20150102    80003   1   3
20150102    80004   -1  0
```

I need to create append number of rows based on variable "number". And let date and time be the same as the numbered rows, while the variable td=0. I want the data like this:

```
date        time    td  number
20150102    80000   -1  0
20150102    80001   -1  2
20150102    80002   1   0
20150102    80003   1   3
20150102    80004   -1  0
20150102    80001   0   NA 
20150102    80001   0   NA
20150102    80003   0   NA
20150102    80003   0   NA
20150102    80003   0   NA
```

Comment: I need to run a loop through this, because I have over 20,000 obs

Comment: I don't understand your expected outcome. Can you clarify the rules? Why does `time` change for first 5 rows? Why the values in the new rows?

Comment: Sorry! I original time should increase by 1, please see my edited version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd generate each column, then bind them into a data frame, then bind them to the original dataframe! No looping required.

Assuming your data frame is called df

```
#Create the date and time using the number column directly.
date <- rep(df$date, times = df$number)
time <- rep(df$time, times = df$number)

#Combine these fields into a data frame and set td to all 0s and number to all NAs
appenddf <- data.frame(date = date, time = time, td = 0, number = NA)

#Bind the data for appending to the original data frame
df <- rbind(df, appenddf)
```

Comment: Good answer! I was thinking on same line but you were fast.  +1

Comment: Thanks! I suspect there might be a stronger answer which doesn't rely on the creation of a separate data frame, but I don't know it off the top of my head :)

Answer (score 0):

This loop will do it using rbind.fill (from plyr), for dataframe `df`:

```
for (i in length(df$n)){
  x = df$n[i]
  while (x > 0){
    df <- rbind.fill(df, df[i,1:2])
    x = x -1
    print(x)
  }
}
#Switch NA's in df$td column to 0
df$td[is.na(df$td)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be achieved using `expandRows` and `separate` function. The expand rows will allow to replicate `rows` with combined values which later on can be separate out and added to original `df`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- setDT(expandRows(df, "number"))[, newsamp := 
sprintf("%d-%d-%d-%d", date, time, 0, NA)][,newsamp] %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  separate(1,c("date", "time", "td", "number"))

rbind(df, df1)

#Result
#       date  time td number
#1  20150102 80000 -1      0
#2  20150102 80001 -1      2
#3  20150102 80002  1      0
#4  20150102 80003  1      3
#5  20150102 80004 -1      0
#6  20150102 80001  0     NA
#7  20150102 80001  0     NA
#8  20150102 80003  0     NA
#9  20150102 80003  0     NA
#10 20150102 80003  0     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> a=rep(1:nrow(dat),dat$number+1)
> transform(dat[c(a[!duplicated(a)],a[duplicated(a)]),-4],num=`length<-`(dat$number,length(a)))
        date  time td num
1   20150102 80000 -1   0
2   20150102 80001 -1   2
3   20150102 80002  1   0
4   20150102 80003  1   3
5   20150102 80004 -1   0
2.1 20150102 80001 -1  NA
2.2 20150102 80001 -1  NA
4.1 20150102 80003  1  NA
4.2 20150102 80003  1  NA
4.3 20150102 80003  1  NA
```